# Are these two PDEs equivalent somehow?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation, linear-pde

I have the one dimensional wave equation for $f(x,y)$ $(1)$:
$$\frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial t^2} = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}$$
and a system of PDE for $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ $(2)$:

\begin{equation} 
\frac{1}{c} \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} \\
\frac{1}{c} \frac{\partial g}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} 
\end{equation}

I know that any solution to $(2)$ for $f$ is a solution to  $(1)$.

**My question is:** Is any solution to $(1)$ for $f$ also a solution to $(2)$ for $f$?

Answer (score 0):

At least locally, yes: If $f$ satisfies (1) in an open ball, then

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left( \frac{1}{c} \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\right) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( c \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\right)$$

Since the open ball is simply connected, there is a function $g$ so that

\begin{align}
 \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} &= \frac 1c \frac{\partial f}{\partial t},\\
 \frac{\partial g}{\partial t} &= c \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
\end{align}

and this is just (2).